# Insert into child table

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to insert an image of a product into a child table called product_images, but it keeps trying to find the column 'path' in the products table.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'path' in 'field list'
```

Here's how I have my controllers/models set up.

PRODUCT MODEL

```php
public function category()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}

public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductImage');
}
```

PRODUCT IMAGES

```php
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Product');
}
```

PRODUCT CONTROLLER

```php
$product = new Product(); $product->category_id = $request->category_id; $product->name = $request->name; $product->price = $request->price;

//upload image
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    //validate
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
    ]);

    $image = $request->image;
    $filename = time() . '-' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = public_path('img/products/' . $filename);
    Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save($path);
    $product->path = 'img/products/' . $filename;
}

$product->images()->save($product);
```

Comment: path is in image table, right? `$product->images->path`

Comment: You're setting `$product->path` in the 2nd to last line, that's why it's trying to save the "path" column on the "products" table

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
$product->images->path = 'img/products/' . $filename;
```

you can use push method to save a model and all of its relationships

```
$product->push();
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this, but it did not insert into the database. The image was saved and the product was added, but the push method did not insert into the product_images table.

Comment: looks like you have many-to-many relationship in between product and images table. If that is the case, you would need to setup the models as directed here. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought I have it set up as one to many? What if I don't want a pivot table? but just have a child table reference the parent table with the column name product_id

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to do this: $image = new ProductImage();

and then $product->images()->save($image);